# POST и GET запросы, API смс-шлюз

Tags: php, post, get

Начал ознакомление с API, который позволяет производить рассылку смс-сообщений.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не въехал с самого начала. Как вызвать этот адрес с помощью GET или POST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите библиотеку cURL. 
Вот здесь посмотрите как работать:
http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/curl

Я бы даже на вашем месте сделал класс для работы с API с помощью данной библиотеки.

Comment: Выдает ошибку: Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_unit(). Сделал все как описано, т.е. скопировал необходимые файлы в  system32, раскоментировал extension=php_curl.dll в php.ini. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Опечатался, там curl_init(), но все равно не работает.

Comment: Перечитал кучу форумов, везде одни и те же советы. Перепробовал все, кинул dll файлы и в папку php/ext и просто в php и в windows/system32 и просто в windows. phpinfo() вообще curl не видит.

Comment: У вас денвер? Restart денвера делали? в логах apache не смотрели ничего не пишет про curl ?

Comment: у меня xampp, соответственно apache. я так понимаю лучше denwer юзать? потому что судя по прочитанному - с ним проблем нет, либо их меньше.

Comment: А я могу как-то сформировать http запрос без curl? Например, с помощью js?

Comment: Лучше юзать виртуальную машину Oracle VirtualBox и LAMP на него ставить. Но для начинающих целей хорош и денвер. У него никаких проблем нету, всё сделано специально, чтобы максимально отдалить начинающего php-шера от сис админской части. Вы можете сформировать с помощью функции file_get_contents - но не рекомендую, эта функция не для этих целей, но сработает. Через JS тоже можно сделать. Используйте JQuery ajax.

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощь, буду разбираться.

Comment: Удачи Вам!) Старайтесь и всё получится!

Comment: У меня почему-то Configuration File (php.ini) Path в C:\Windows. Пытался поменять в конфиге apache - не вышло. В итоге пока что просто закинул туда php.ini и curl заработал.

Answer (score 2):

Его можно вызвать с помощью GET или POST. В данном случае, лучше GET:

```
echo file_get_contents('https://smsc.ru/...');
```

Comment: Если поступить таким образом, без применения cURL - появляется ошибка "Failed to open stream"

Comment: Если на localhost, то там https запросы не послать.

Answer (score 1):

Сушествует множество клиентов которые могут делать `HTTP`(`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` ...)  запросы (включая ваш браузер).

Если хочется разобраться то:

**Sockets** - http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php (Сокеты могут делать много чего еще.)
**cURL** - http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

А если просто что бы работало то:

**Guzzle** - https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle